# Should we respect non Muslims or not?

Tags: non-muslim

Allah says:( And who are more unjust than those who prevent the name of Allah from being mentioned in His mosques and strive toward their destruction. It is not for them to enter them except in fear. For them in this world is disgrace, and they will have in the Hereafter a great punishment.) (2:114)

Because there is disgrace in this world for them,should we respect them or not?

Comment: Why not? This disgrace is from Allah(SWT) onto them and not from us. We are not responsible for their actions. The prophet(SAW) should be your example. From what I know, the prophet would never disgrace a disbeliever just because they are disbelievers but will instead try to turn them into believers by being kind towards them and spreading the word of Allah.  Islam is a religion of peace and Muslims should always exhibit attributes of peace wherever they go to anyone they meet, either a disbeliever or not!

Answer (score 1):

لهم في الدنيا خزي (for them in this world is disgrace) includes what the believers do to them, such as fighting and subjugation.

> قيل القتل للحربي ، والجزية للذمي ، عن قتادة . السدي : الخزي لهم في الدنيا قيام المهدي ، وفتح عمورية ورومية وقسطنطينية ، وغير ذلك من مدنهم ، على ما ذكرناه في كتاب التذكرة . ومن جعلها في قريش جعل الخزي عليهم في الفتح
>
> It has been said: This is killing of a Harbi and Jizya for a Dhimmi, that is narrated from Qatada. And it is natted from as-Suddi: It means the establishment of the Mahdi and the conquest of Amorium, Rome, Constantinople and their other cities. ... And those who said that this verse is about the Quraish said that disgrace means the conquest (of Makkah).
>
> <sup>— [Tafsir al-Qurtubi](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura2-aya114.html#qortobi)</sup>

Regarding your title question, that depends on the type of non-muslim and on what you mean by 'respect'. A Harbi is certainly not respected in a great deal of matters in which it is obligatory to respect a Dhimmi, Musta’min or Mu‘aahid, such as in regard to the sanctity of their life or property etc.